# Trying to pass UIImage from one ViewController to my GameScene in spriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I thought it would be interesting to learn how to pass an image from an imagePicker to my GameScene to use as a SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: UIImage)) but i keep getting an error after selecting my image and pressing a button to go into my gameScene

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "startSegue") {

        var gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as GameScene

        gameViewController.imageToPass = pickedImage.image

    }
```

anyone know what im doing wrong?

keep getting exc_breakpoint (code=exc_i386_bpt, subcode 0x0)
when initializing gameViewController as GameScene

I am trying to pass imageToPass to the GameScene.swift that is created when i create a new game project in Xcode

class GameScene: SKScene {

```
var imageToPass = UIImage()
var bird = SKSpriteNode()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var birdTexture = SKTexture(image: imageToPass)
    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(bird)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination view controller is a `UIViewController` or its subclass. Not an `SKScene`. So I don't think it can be converted to `GameScene`.  `GameScene` is usually a property of a `UIViewController` that holds it. In my project the `UIViewController` is called `GameViewController`. `GameViewController` has a property called `gameScene`

So the code should be

```
if let gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? GameViewController
{
    gameViewController.imageToPass = pickedImage.image
}
```

create a property in GameViewController called `imageToPass`. Set the `imageToPass` to `GameScene.imageToPass` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var pickedImage : UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            let skView = self.view as SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            scene.imageToPass = pickedImage

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a property observer on imageToPass to change it dynamically.

```
var bird : SKSpriteNode!

var imageToPass : UIImage!
    {
    didSet
    {
        createBird()
    }
}

func createBird()
{
    var birdTexture = SKTexture(image: imageToPass)
    bird?.removeFromParent()
    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    self.addChild(bird)
}
```

Comment: hmm I edited my post...your solution still didnt work even though it sounds right to me... I might be doing something wrong again

Comment: you might have to create the bird after you set the imageToPass. I think didMoveToView is executed before you set the imageToPass

Comment: thanks a lot no more crash....
but how do I get the sprite to load onto the view now? (amateur question, still learning....)

Comment: didn't understand the question? I am adding the sprite to the view in the createBird function

Comment: check the modified code. i changed how set the imageToPass.

Answer (score 0):

In the default SpriteKit implementation, the View Controller created is a `GameViewController`. In Interface Builder, it has for its view an SKView. In `viewDidLoad`, the key lines are

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
    // Configure the view.
    let skView = self.view as SKView 
    /* more setup */
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

It looks like you've edited your question to reflect this. I'm not a SpriteKit expert, but if you get `imageToPass` to the `GameViewController`, then you should be able to pass it to your GameScene in viewDidLoad before it's presented. Good luck.

Note "GameScene.swift" is just the name of the text file that contains the code, so you wouldn't pass anything to it, the class is created in `class GameScene: SKScene { /* class properties and methods */`

### Original Answer:

Are you sure the `destinationViewController` is a `GameScene`? *Really* sure? Because you're using `as`, you're force downcasting the segue view controller as a "GameScene".

Take advantage of Swift's safety features:

```
if var gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? GameScene {
    gameViewController.imageToPass = pickedImage.image
}
```

or using optional chaining:

```
var gameViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? GameScene
gameViewController?.imageToPass = pickedImage.image
```

The pickedImage won't get through if not a GameScene, regardless, but you won't get a crash.

EDIT: By the way, it really should be `GameSceneViewController` so its clear everywhere it's a View Controller. If it's not a View Controller, that's a problem and has no chance to work.